# Admin port configuration not found' error while setting up Glassfish config in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish-3

When setting up Glassfish in IntelliJ IDEA I get the following Error message ´Admin port configuration not found´.

Now I searched high an low but I found no place where I can set the admin port.

Searching Google all I found was a [dead link on the JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/468196/vc/Admin-port-configuration-not-found). So Im not the first but the solution is lost.

Does anybody know what is to be done?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IDEA GlassFish integration detects admin port from the file: `<domain folder>/config/domain.xml`

XPaths checked:

```
/configs/config[@name='server-config']/http-service/http-listener[@id='admin-listener']/@port
/configs/config[@name='server-config']/network-config/network-listeners/network-listener[@protocol='admin-listener']/@port
```

If `domain.xml` can't be found or both XPaths aren't valid you'll be warned with the message `Admin port configuration not found`.

Comment: That really helped. Found my domain.xml filled with NULs after last glassfish shutdown.

Comment: had the same problem my domain.xml was completely deleted

Answer (score 1):

I think the broken link should be http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-25807 and points to the Glassfish HOME configuration as the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It was happening to me because my domain.xml was not in the /domain1/config folder.

Instead I had this two files domain.xml.bak and domain.xml~.

What I did is create a new domain.xml with the content of domain.xml~. Then remove the two fields (.bak and .xml~) And then run again glassfish.

That worked for me.

Why my domain.xml sundenly disappear stills a mistery to me. :S

Answer (score 1):

First, you can delete domain.xml.bak
Second, go to IDEA - Edit Configurations - GlassFish. Set an absolute path in the field "Server Domain", for example: C:\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1.
So, check field "JRE" if you wrote path to JDK in file "asenv". This path must be the same as the value from server configuraton.

Comment: Hi Cursor, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide an explanation as to why your answer is different / more relevant than the previous answers? This is a very old question, so if something has changed it would be helpful for other readers to have that context :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple and straightforward way to handle this error in *IntelliJ IDEA* is changing

> `domain1`

to equivalent full path, e.g.:

> `C:\glassfish6\glassfish\domains\domain1`

in **Run/Debug Configurations** pane of Glassfish integration:

[image]