# Intellij IDEA 13 and Glassfish 4 integration - Error: Admin port configuration not found

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish, glassfish-4, intellij-13

I have IntelliJ IDEA 13 and Glassfish 4.  I created a new domain in Glassfish using command:

`asadmin create-domain --portbase 10000 --nopassword test-domain`

Then, in Intellij, I setup a run configuration for Glassfish specifying Server Domain: test-domain.  On the bottom of the config dialog, it reports:

"Error: Admin port configuration not found."

I saw this post on SO: [Admin port configuration not found' error while setting up Glassfish config in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010418/admin-port-configuration-not-found-error-while-setting-up-glassfish-config-in-i)  ...but I *do* find the port configured under:

/configs/config[@name='server-config']/network-config/network-listeners/network-listener[@protocol='admin-listener']/@port

as follows:

`<network-listener port="10048" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>`

I'm wondering if something changed in Intellij 13 or Glassfish 4 that has caused this issue to return?  Or am I missing something?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, simply allow `Read & Write` privilege of your domain directory (whuch includes inner directories & files) to IntelliJ.

At least it works for my case. (Mac OS)

Comment: thank you from the future! still a good answer 4 years on! ta.